# How to deal with exhaustive-deps when a required dependency must not trigger a call on update?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In my functional React component, I have a function that is used both on component mount and in some child event:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
const myFunction = useCallback(() => {
    // do something with count, such as a fetch or console.log for example
}, [])

useEffect(() => {   
    myFunction()
}, [myFunction])

return (
    <button onClick={myFunction}>
        myButton
    </button>
)
```

`myFunction` must be called on mount and when the button is clicked. However, the classic React way of doing this implies to declare `count` as a dependency in `useCallback`, which would trigger a call of `myFunction` each time `count` is updated by another part of the program, which I do not want. `count` must be able to be updated without triggering `myFunction`.

I cannot find a clean solution for doing this. Is there one? Or should I write my code a different way? What's the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, there's a simple solution. Instead of using the `count` state variable inside of `useCallback`, and therefore making it a dependency of the `useCallback` hook, you could just use the callback parameter of the state updater function. So instead of:

```
const myFunction = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1)
}, [])
```

You could write it like this:

```
const myFunction = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)
}, [])
```

Another way, for more complex instances, would be to use the [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook instead of `useState`. Since you would be using `useReducer`'s `dispatch` function to update the state, there wouldn't any need to have the `state` as a dependency in the `useCallback` hook.

```
const [count, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + action.by;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}, 0);

const myFunction = useCallback(() => {
  dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT", by: 1 });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  myFunction();
}, [myFunction]);

return (
  <div>
    <p>{count}</p>
    <button onClick={myFunction}>myButton</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: these are interesting solutions, however they consist in removing all references of count from the function. what if I need to use count for some business logic in the function? I simplified my function for this SO post, but I simplified it too much, I will add this specificity in the code example.

Comment: @papillon if you needed to use `count` for some business logic, then you would use it inside of your reducer and from `myFunction` just dispatch the action which will update `count` state.

Answer (score 1):

Use React [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for `setState`:

```
setCount(count => count + 1);
```

This way you do not need to add `count` to dependencies.

Comment: this is an interesting solution, however it consists in remove all references of count from the function. what if I need to use count for some business logic in the function? I simplified my function for this SO post, but I simplified it too much, I will add this specificity in the code example.

Comment: You probably can refactor your code to prevent that. But if it still cause an issue, you can use `useRef` as an instance value and make sure that your function only runs once. [See here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables). Note that refs are objects and you don't have to include them in the array of dependencies, because they will not change. Also they will NOT cause a render if their value (`ref.current`) changes.

Comment: Not sure how I could refactor my code. I am building a map which view can be moved by clicking and dragging it, like Google Maps. Some variable, `view`, corresponds to the center of the map. When click+dragging the map, it is updated to move the map accordingly. Based on its new position, I fetch the data on the map corresponding to this new position. However, I do not want the fetch to happen at every mouse movement, which would be way too often. I want the fetch to happen only when releasing the click. The function that fetches the world data must not be called when `view` changes.

Comment: 1. Instead of fetching data in `useEffect`, you can use [mouseup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event).
2. You may debounce your fetch request.

Comment: I need to call it on component mount, and on mouseup. Because when the page first loads, there must be some data displayed.

Comment: debouncing is quite a good idea, I'll consider it, ty

Comment: 1. Call your function on `mousup` event.  2. Call it in `useEffect`, but keep track of whether your function has been called or not using ref. [Something like this link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/08/27/react-how-to-check-if-a-component-is-mounted-or-unmounted). Call your function conditionally based on the ref. 3. Example of refactoring your code would be: instead of reading the `center` variable from your state in your function, pass it as an argument, so your `useEffect` will be decoupled from the `view` state. I cannot help more without a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: that's already very helpful, thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

As of august 2022, this actually happens to be a flaw in the design of the framework. I went over many posts on the Internet and did not find any solution. The only significant messages that I found were people complaining about this mechanism not being suitable for many legit use cases. I guess there isn't really a standard solution for this problem. Personally, I decided to disable the warning globally on my project, because it is a pain more than it is helpful.

I won't mark my answer as "accepted" because I deem it unsatisfied, but for whomever will read this, I suggest taking a look at the other answers on this post. They do not solve the problem but give useful tricks that might fit your need.